# This code works correctly on chrome but not in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I tried this code but I can't understand why it's not working on safari

```js
function numberWithCommas(field) {
  let element = document.getElementById(field.id);
  let amount = element.value.replace(/,/g, "");
  if (amount.charAt(0) == "-") {
    amount = "-" + amount.substring(1).replace(/-/g, "");
  } else {
    amount = amount.replace(/-/g, "");
  }
  element.value = amount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

function checkAmount() {
  let element = document.getElementById("m_currency");
  let newamount = element.value.replace(/,/g, "");
  console.log(newamount);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="12" name="m_currency" id="m_currency" class="currency" onkeyup="numberWithCommas(this)" onchange="checkAmount()">
```

the first function add a comma for the thousands and works for both browsers, the second one, that should delete the comma, works only on chrome

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect the problem isn't that `checkAmount` doesn't work, but rather that Safari isn't firing the `change` event when you expect it to. (I'm certainly seeing that with mobile Safari using a local copy of your code. And I do **not** understand it, I've only heard of this being an issue in Safari with `select` elements, not `input` elements.) You might try the `input` and/or `blur` events instead, but note that `input` fires on every change, not just when the field loses focus.

Comment: man you're a savior! it seems to be working with onblur instead of onchange